# How do I echo previously chosen dropdown datepicker value in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datepicker

I used jquery datepicker to input start_date in my form. I set today's date as the minimum date as well as the default date every time a new entry is created. How do I echo previously chosen dropdown datepicker value in codeigniter?
This is what I have in entry adding.

```
<span style="font-size: 10pt" class="label label-info">Start Date</span>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="start_date">
    <td><?php echo form_error('start_date'); ?></td>
```

I tried the following code to echo previously chosen start date so I can start from there to do editing, but it did not work properly..

```
    <span style="font-size: 10pt" class="label label-info">Start Date</span>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="start_date" value="<?php echo set_value('start_date', $job? date("YY/MM/DD",strtotime($job->start_date)) : date("YY/MM/DD")); ?>">
    <td><?php echo form_error('start_date'); ?></td>
```

Any help is appreciated. Have a nice weekend! :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. But I would also like to thank another user who gave me the possible reason behind my dropdown echo issue to begin with.

Anyway, to echo previously chosen dropdown value in datepicker, here's what you need to do:
In your document's head, put:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
  $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});
 });
</script>
```

In your document's body, you should put:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="start_date" value="<?php echo set_value('start_date', $job? date("Y/m/d",strtotime($job->start_date)) : date("Y/m/d")); ?>">
```

Hope this helps. :)